# Minimize .NET MAUI application on closing to Dock Panel in MacOS

Tags: .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit, .net-mac

I have .NET MAUI project developed for Windows and MacOS desktops. I want to minimize the application to the Dock on closing in MacOS platform, i.e. I want to hide the window but the application should continue the work in background (you can see how it works when you closing for example most of the messengers). In Windows platform I've made the functionality to minimize it to the tray with tray icon, tray menu and all of this kind of functionalities, but in MacOS I cannot find the solution. I will be very appreciated if someone can tell me how to do it.

Actually I've tried to use LifecycleEvents in MauiProgram.cs, but it's not configured as I see. Also I've tried to add deactivated event for window in App.xaml.cs, but there are no possibility to make it hidden and cancel this event.

Comment: when I run the Maui program on the Mac platform, I try to right-click the app icon in the dock and select “keep in dock“, The app will remain in the dock when the program is closed, but the app will also be quit. Do you want the effect to be that the app remains in the dock and the app is still running when the app is closed?

Comment: I want to keep app running when closing the window. The manual setting "Keep in Dock" option just put the application in Dock for further  opening the app without finding it finder, but it closing when the window is closing. So the main problem is the keep application working on window closing and show it in Dock without manual setting "Keep in Dock" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Based on Apple's response](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252061383), your requirement can be achieved when the Maui application supports multiple windows.

Specifically, you can add the `SceneDelegate` class to the Maui project and add the relevant xml to the macatalyst's `Info.plist` file, Then override the `OpenWindow` method in the app.xaml file:

```
public override void OpenWindow(Window window)
{
    base.OpenWindow(window);
    Window secondWindow = new Window(new YourPage());
    Application.Current.OpenWindow(secondwindow)
}
```

For more details, you can refer to the [Multi-window support document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/windows#multi-window-support).

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. It really helps. Actually after these changes I had a problem with locked flyout menu, after reopening the window all controls in not current contentview disappeared. But anyway I redeveloped all my menu functionality, create my own menu control and after changing Info.plist and adding SceneDelegate class it work like a charm. Thanks again!